# How to draw polygons in python (giving cordenates) and number its edges?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gis

I have a list of agroforestry plots (polygons) in python. Every polygon es represented as latitude/longitude.

```
 polygon1_coords = [
    (11.946898956, -86.109286248),
    (11.947196373, -86.109159886),
    (11.947092456, -86.108962101),
    (11.946897164, -86.10886504),
    (11.946898956, -86.109286248 )]

polygon2_coords = [
    (11.946895372, -86.110055411),
    (11.94718204,  -86.110046254),
    (11.947194581, -86.109172705),
    (11.946900747, -86.109313718),
    (11.946895372, -86.110055411)
    ]
```

I need a way to draw those polygons as an image and place numbers on its edges. A polygon need to also be represented with a letter. This is an example of what I need

[image: Polygons I need to draw]

As you can see I need to be able to represent several polygons in the same picture and number its edges individually. How can I do it in python?

Comment: Maybe learn `matplotlib` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing from the previous answer, but adding the label not just at the edges, but also inside the polygon, you can use `shapely`'s [representative_point](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.representative_point) to find a place for your label, see:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

polygon = [
    (12.132481, -86.239511),
    (12.132093,-86.239344 ),
    (12.132287, -86.23876),
    (12.132481, -86.239511)
]

x = [p[0] for p in polygon]
y = [p[1] for p in polygon]

label_location = Polygon(polygon).representative_point()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)

#[:-1] slice because we only want to print 3 edges, not where they meet
for i, p in enumerate(polygon[:-1]):
    ax.annotate(f"{i+1}", (p[0], p[1]))

ax.annotate("B", label_location.coords[:][0])

plt.show()
```

Plots:

[image: polygon plot with labels]